# Problem while installing virtual box

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I'm trying to install **virtualbox-4.3** from software centre. But here showing an error message like this.[image: Error message]

Comment: We don't see the full error message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to remove virtualbox before (in terminal try:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox
```

if you get an error that virtualbox is not found try this:

```
 sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -i virtualbox
```

then you should get a list of the installed packages with "virtualbox" in their name...
remove them and try to install the new virtualbox version.

hope this helps!